# cc1plus: error: include: Value too large for defined data type when compiling with g++

Tags: visual-studio, g++

I am making a project that should compile on Windows and Linux. I have made the project in Visual Studio and then made a makefile for linux. I created all the files in Windows with VS.

It compiles and runs perfectly in VS but when I run the makefile and it runs g++ I get

```
$ g++ -c -I include -o obj/Linux_x86/Server.obj src/Server.cpp
cc1plus: error: include: Value too large for defined data type
cc1plus: error: src/Server.cpp: Value too large for defined data type
```

The code is nothing more than a Hello World atm. I just wanted to make sure that everything was working before I started development. I have tried searching but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You won't get an answer without giving away your code, i suspect.

Comment: Can you post the code of the line which it complains about? Also, which g++ for windows are you using? MinGW, cygwin,...?

Comment: This is running on Linux. That is all the output I get.

Comment: That's the formatted error message for `EOVERFLOW`. Sounds like `Server.cpp` is a huge file (correction: TU) so `Server.obj` is getting too big.

Comment: @Johannes So Android, can you post result of `cat src/Server.cpp | wc`?

Comment: @pajton, that won't process preprocessor directives... `g++ -E -I include src/Server.cpp | wc` may do it. But it may be small and still create a huge object file (templates?)

Comment: Like I said, Server.cpp is just a hello world atm. It's 6 lines long. I think I might have found the problem but don't know why. All this is in a folder mounted from a samba share to my Windows computer. I copied all the files into another directory on the Linux computer and it stopped happening. Is there anyway that I can make it work in the mounted folder?

Comment: If it is a problem with mounted fs, then probably you do not have enough privileges be it mounted fs privileges or on windows share.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have found a solution on Ubuntu at least. I, like you have noticed that the error only occurs on mounted samba shares - it seems to come from g++ 'stat'ing the file, the inode returns a very large value.

When mounting the share add ,nounix,noserverino to the options, ie:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=me,pass=secret,nounix,noserverino //server/share /mount
```

I found the info at http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=85999

Comment: The option `nounix` should not be necessary. You can use only the `noserverino` option. I used both options and when I was compiling a large project, all files were compiled and not only the modified ones.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem. I compiled a project in a CIFS mounted samba share. With one Linux kernel the compilation was done, but using an other Linux kernel (2.6.32.5), I got similar error message: "Value too large for defined data type". When I used the proposed "nounix,noserverino" CIFS mounting option, the problem was fixed. So in that case there is a problem with CIFS mounting, so the error message is misleading, as there are no big files.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU Core Utils:](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type)

> 27 Value too large for defined data type
>
> It means that your version of the utilities were not compiled with
>   large file support enabled. The GNU utilities do support large files
>   if they are compiled to do so. You may want to compile them again and
>   make sure that large file support is enabled. This support is
>   automatically configured by autoconf on most systems. But it is
>   possible that on your particular system it could not determine how to
>   do that and therefore autoconf concluded that your system did not
>   support large files.
>
> The message "Value too large for defined data type" is a system error
>   message reported when an operation on a large file is attempted using
>   a non-large file data type. Large files are defined as anything larger
>   than a signed 32-bit integer, or stated differently, larger than 2GB.
>
> Many system calls that deal with files return values in a "long int"
>   data type. On 32-bit hardware a long int is 32-bits and therefore this
>   imposes a 2GB limit on the size of files. When this was invented that
>   was HUGE and it was hard to conceive of needing anything that large.
>   Time has passed and files can be much larger today. On native 64-bit
>   systems the file size limit is usually 2GB * 2GB. Which we will again
>   think is huge.
>
> On a 32-bit system with a 32-bit "long int" you find that you can't
>   make it any bigger and also maintain compatibility with previous
>   programs. Changing that would break many things! But many systems make
>   it possible to switch into a new program mode which rewrites all of
>   the file operations into a 64-bit program model. Instead of "long"
>   they use a new data type called "off_t" which is constructed to be
>   64-bits in size. Program source code must be written to use the off_t
>   data type instead of the long data type. This is typically done by
>   defining -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 or some such. It is system dependent.
>   Once done and once switched into this new mode most programs will
>   support large files just fine.
>
> See the next question if you have inadvertently created a large file
>   and now need some way to deal with it.

Comment: I was getting the "Value too large for defined data type" error, trying to call stat. Adding #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64 to my code solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

12 years after this question was posted, I get the same error, when building my c++ project in docker on ubuntu 20.04 in Windows 11 WSL2 using an old 32-bit compiler (gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabi-2012.01-20120125_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++).

The issue is related to mounting of the windows filesystem into WSL, where we get 64 bit inodes, not supported by the old 32 bit toolchain, see also [The 64 bit inode problem](https://www.mjr19.org.uk/sw/inodes64.html)

As a quick workaround you can build if you move your project into the home folder of the ubuntu.

An alternative solution is to replace the stat() with LD_PRELOAD as described in [Build on Windows 10 with WSL](https://thesofproject.github.io/latest/developer_guides/tech/compile_wsl.html), section "Fix stat in 32-bit binaries". This shall be done in the docker image. To compile inode64.c I had to additionally add 32 bit header files with

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `mergerfs` filesystem, removing `use_ino` option will solve the issue: https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs/issues/485

Answer (score -1):

I think your g++ parameters are a bit off, or conflicting.

-c compile only
-I directory of your includes (just plain include might be ambiguous. Try full path)
-o outfile (but -c says compile only)

Comment: I think you are confusing `-c` with `-fsyntax-only`.