# Why no line number for the g++ compile error?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, g++

I'm trying to compile a 64bit C++ app on Linux using g++. My current problem is no line number is given for the compile error. Also, it seems like it is complaining about using 64 bit integers, but I won't know unless I get a line number. Here's the output - am I missing some switch to turn on line numbers?

```
g++  -v -m64 -Wall  -c -o Linker.o Linker.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.5 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multiarch-defaults=i386-linux-gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.5 --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-m64' '-Wall' '-c' '-o' 'Linker.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultilib 64 -D_GNU_SOURCE Linker.cpp -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -quiet -dumpbase Linker.cpp -m64 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip Linker.o -Wall -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/cc3qPPyP.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) version 4.5.2 (i686-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.5.2, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.0.0-p8, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=63 --param ggc-min-heapsize=63500
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.5/i686-linux-gnu/64"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../../i686-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.5
 /usr/include/c++/4.5/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
cc1plus: fatal error: Linker.cpp: Value too large for defined data type
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Linker.o] Error 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [cc1plus: error: include: Value too large for defined data type when compiling with g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438890/cc1plus-error-include-value-too-large-for-defined-data-type-when-compiling-wit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the error is not related to the source code, but with the filesystem which Linker.cpp resides in, try copying the file to a ext filesystem.

Take a look here:
[cc1plus: error: include: Value too large for defined data type when compiling with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438890/cc1plus-error-include-value-too-large-for-defined-data-type-when-compiling-wit)

Which is the filesystem which Linker.c is on?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fatal error within the compiler itself; it's not complaining about an error in your code!

The answer to this similar question may be of help: [cc1plus: error: include: Value too large for defined data type when compiling with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438890).